# Preon on Android

Tags: java, android, dalvik, preon

I tried to run a sample Preon application on Android 2.1 without luck. I wonder if running a Preon application on Android is even possible. How hard would it be to make the Preon framework Dalvik friendly?

Preon is a Java library for building codecs for bitstream-compressed data in a declarative way. Think JAXB or Hibernate, but then for binary encoded data written by Wilfred Springer.

---

Below are my finding when trying to run a simple application that uses Preon in Android:

Preon has a dependency on Pecia. Pecia indirectly depends on stax-api which is not supported out of the box in Android. Is the stax-api used in the Preon core processing? Can I exclude the stax-api from the Preon dependencies?

After excluding pecia from the dependencies (without knowing the consequences), I found out that preon brings multiple copies of the log4j.properties file. I suggest moving log4j.properties files to the /src/test/resources directory on the preon and pecia projects to avoid bringing them with the classes.

Because duplicated log4j.properties files, the android-maven-plugin fails at the package goal with the following message:

[INFO] java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: log4j.properties

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 19.717s

[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 23 14:30:55 PST 2011

[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/62M

Comment: I only know these preons (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preon). Could you explain for me what Preon is?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/preon/

Comment: That's the old location. New location is here: http://preon.codehaus.org/

Comment: Can you explain what issues you ran into?

Comment: Wilfred, I updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I will answer my own question. It is POSSIBLE to use the Preon framework in Android. However, Preon does not work out of the box. I managed to run a sample application after doing the following changes:

 1. I moved all log4.properties in the
    preon projects to their
    corresponding /src/test/resources
    directory.

 2. Remove dependency on pecia.

 3. Embedded the following interfaces from pecia in preon-binding:
    
DocumentElement.java

Documenter.java

Para.java

ParaContents.java

4.  org.codehaus.preon.code.Codecs:

        I commented out the following imports and all its related code (the ones that won't compile after this change):

              import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;

           import nl.flotsam.pecia.builder.ArticleDocument;
    
           import nl.flotsam.pecia.builder.base.DefaultArticleDocument;
       
        import nl.flotsam.pecia.builder.base.DefaultDocumentBuilder;
         
      import nl.flotsam.pecia.builder.html.HtmlDocumentBuilder;
            
   import nl.flotsam.pecia.builder.xml.StreamingXmlWriter;
            
   import nl.flotsam.pecia.builder.xml.XmlWriter;

5.  org.codehaus.preon.codec.ObjectCodeFactory
        
commented out:
        
    /*         target.document(codec.getCodecDescriptor().reference(CodecDescriptor.Adjective.THE, false));
*/

Suggestions:

I suggest to refactor preon code to have documentation code separated from runtime dependencies.

Wilfred, If you want, I could contribute to your project.

Oscar.

Comment: Nice! Drop me an email on wilfredspringer at gmail dot com, and we can talk.

Answer (score 0):

you also could take a look at [Java Binary Block Parser](https://github.com/raydac/java-binary-block-parser), the library is compatible with Android 2.1+